# ogr2ogr equivalent command as QGIS "save as SpatiaLite"

Tags: qgis, export, ogr2ogr, spatialite

I have a Layer, load from a WKT file in QGIS with and geometry field called 'geometry':

This is the wkt source:

```
type;label;geometry
0x10e04;Rego de San Xurxo;LINESTRING(-8.00676 43.54270,-8.00953 43.54159,-8.01118 43.54088,-8.01197 43.54056,-8.01208 43.54049)
...
```

I load into a layer with (Layer-Add Layer->Add delimited text layer) and all OK, then i 'Save as' ->SpatiaLite.... and I get a file example.sqlite. If I load into and SQlite Browser, i can see a field called "geometry" with BLOB content.

How is the equivalent command to QGIS "save as -> Spatialite" in ogr2ogr from the originl WKT file ?

All my attempts give me a example.sqlite but with a field "geometry" with text content, and this file can not be loaded into QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a VRT with your WKT as the source, for instance:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="linedata">
       <SrcDataSource>input.csv</SrcDataSource>
      <GeometryType>wkbMultiLineString</GeometryType>
 <LayerSRS>EPSG:3857</LayerSRS>
 <GeometryField encoding="WKT" field='geom' > </GeometryField >
     </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

You can then convert your VRT (e.g. input.vrt) to a Spatialite database (output.db) as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite output.db input.vrt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, dmci, I got it, now I have a field called 'geom' with geometry at BLOB format, but also I have a 'duplicate' field  with geometry into original 'string' format.  Is it possible to avoid the original string field into new sqlite file?

Comment: maybe ensure that you use either 'geom'  or 'geometry' in both  your WKT and VRT, i.e. don't mix them.

Comment: Thanks dmci. I respong mysefl:  Add tags <Field name='field' src="source_field"/> for every  field I need (avoid not necessary) I will get only selected fields from source.  ;)   I'm happy now... thanks.